How to Extract Constructor Params from Deployed Bytescode
Constructor Params are written to the end of the contract bytecode. However, it's hard to identify where Constructor Params start and end just by looking at the low-level bytecode.
Of course, there is some opcode-based logic in the creation code that returns the length of the Constructor Params, but this can also depend on the Solidity version or CREATE2, so it's hard to use as a reference.
Is there a good way to do this?
